# Retornar Valor com MoneyMask

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função que realiza um calculo e altera o valor de do meu componente. Porém gostaria que ela retornasse o valor em reais já com a Máscara, estou utilizando o `MaskMoney` mas ta retornando `NaN`. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue a função:

```js
function retornaResultado(num) {

    // Recupera valores
    var iuc = document.querySelector("#iuc");
    var gi = document.querySelector("#gi");
    var isb = document.querySelector("#isb");
    var cap = document.querySelector("#cap");
    var ca = document.querySelector("#ca");
  
    /*Tentando adicionar a máscara no campo*/
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ca").maskMoney({
            showSymbol: true,
            symbol: "R$",
            decimal: ",",
            thousands: "."
        });
    });

    //Realiza Cálculo
    var risb = calculoISB();
    var rcap = calculoCAP();
    var calcgi = parseFloat(risb) + parseFloat(rcap) + parseFloat(iuc.value);
    
    gi.textContent = calcgi.toFixed(3);
    isb.textContent = calculoISB();
    cap.textContent = calculoCAP();
    var result = calcgi * num;
    
    /* Aqui fica o campo no qual quero alterar o valor já com a mask(R$)*/
    ca.textContent = result.toFixed(2);

}
```